# QGLWidget, отрисовка множества точек в окне OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Пытаюсь рисовать множество точек. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как отрисовать точки так, чтобы в начальный момент времени они все попадали на экран. Ещё проблема с приближением и вращением, не пойму как это сделать относительно центра ограничивающего параллелепипеда или экрана. Прошу вашей помощи.

BoundingBox.h

```
#include "vector3d.h"

class BoundingBox
{
public:
    BoundingBox() : valid(false) {}
    void add(Vector3D aPoint)
    {
        if (valid)
        {
            if (aPoint.x < minCorner.x)
                minCorner.x = aPoint.x;
            else if (aPoint.x > maxCorner.x)
                maxCorner.x = aPoint.x;

            if (aPoint.y < minCorner.y)
                minCorner.y = aPoint.y;
            else if (aPoint.y > maxCorner.y)
                maxCorner.y = aPoint.y;

            if (aPoint.z < minCorner.z)
                minCorner.z = aPoint.z;
            else if (aPoint.z > maxCorner.z)
                maxCorner.z = aPoint.z;
        }
        else
        {
            maxCorner = minCorner = aPoint;
            valid = true;
        }
    }

    void clear()
    {
        valid = false;
        minCorner = maxCorner = Vector3D(0,0,0);
    }

    Vector3D getCenter() { return Vector3D((minCorner.x + maxCorner.x) * 0.5, (minCorner.y + maxCorner.y) * 0.5, (minCorner.z + maxCorner.z) * 0.5); }

public:
    Vector3D minCorner;
    Vector3D maxCorner;
    bool valid;
};
```

Vector3D.h

```
class Vector3D
{
public:
    Vector3D(double x1 = 0, double y1 = 0, double z1 = 0) : x(x1), y(y1), z(z1) {}
    double x, y, z;
};
```

glwidget.h

```
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <vector>

#include "vector3d.h"

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
public:
    GLWidget(QWidget* parent = NULL);
    ~GLWidget() {}

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL( int w, int h );

public slots:
    void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* event );
    void mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent* event );
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* pe) ;

private:
    GLfloat xRot, yRot, zRot, scale, xTrans, yTrans, zTrans;
    QPoint lastPos;
    std::vector<Vector3D> m_points;
};
```

glwidget.cpp

```
#include "glwidget.h"
#include "boundingbox.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <QMouseEvent>

double random(double min, double max)
{
    return (double)(rand())/RAND_MAX*(max - min) + min;
}

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    std::srand(std::time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
        Vector3D V;
        V.x = random(1000.0,10000.0);
        V.y = random(1000.0,10000.0);
        V.z = random(1000.0,10000.0);
        m_points.push_back(V);
    }

    xRot = yRot = zRot = xTrans = yTrans = zTrans = 0.0;
    scale = 1.0;
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    BoundingBox bbox;

    for(int i = 0; i < m_points.size(); i++)
        bbox.add(m_points[i]);

    Vector3D boxC = bbox.getCenter();

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    double dL = 100;
    glOrtho(bbox.minCorner.x - dL, bbox.maxCorner.x + dL,
            bbox.minCorner.y - dL, bbox.maxCorner.y + dL,
            bbox.minCorner.z - dL, bbox.maxCorner.z + dL);

    glScalef( scale, scale, scale );
    glTranslatef(-boxC.x, 0, 0);
    glTranslatef(0, -boxC.y, 0);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -boxC.z);
    glRotatef( xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef( yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef( zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    glTranslatef( -xTrans, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glTranslatef( 0.0, yTrans, 0.0 );
    glTranslatef( 0.0, 0.0, zTrans );

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < m_points.size(); i++)
    {
        Vector3D P = m_points[i];
        glVertex3d(P.x, P.y, P.z);
    }
    glEnd();

}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport( 0, 0, (GLint)w, (GLint)h );
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum( -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 15.0 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
}

void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    lastPos = event->pos();
    updateGL();
}

void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent* event )
{
    float dx = (event->pos().x()-lastPos.x());
    float dy = (event->pos().y()-lastPos.y());

    if(event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        xRot += dy;
        yRot += dx;
    }
    else if(event->buttons() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        xTrans -= dx/(1.0);
        yTrans -= dy/(1.0);
    }

    lastPos = event->pos();

    updateGL();
}

void GLWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* pe)
{
    if ((pe->delta())>0)
        scale*=1.1;
    else if ((pe->delta())<0)
        scale/=1.1;

    updateGL();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможное решение, полученное способом "пальцем в небо"

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    BoundingBox bbox;

    for(int i = 0; i < m_points.size(); i++)
        bbox.add(m_points[i]);

    Vector3D boxC = bbox.getCenter();

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    double dL = 1000;
    double maxLen = std::max(std::max(bbox.maxCorner.x-bbox.minCorner.x, bbox.maxCorner.y-bbox.minCorner.y), bbox.maxCorner.z-bbox.minCorner.z);

    double f_scale = scale;
    if(scale < 1)
        f_scale = 1/scale;

    glOrtho(boxC.x-maxLen/1 - dL, boxC.x + maxLen/1 + dL, boxC.y-maxLen/1 - dL, boxC.y + maxLen/1 + dL, -(f_scale)*std::fabs(boxC.z-maxLen/1 - dL), f_scale*std::fabs(boxC.z + maxLen/1 + dL));

    glTranslated(boxC.x, 0, 0);
    glTranslated(0, boxC.y, 0);
    glTranslated(0, 0, boxC.z);
    glScalef( scale, scale, scale );
    glTranslated(-boxC.x, 0, 0);
    glTranslated(0, -boxC.y, 0);
    glTranslated(0, 0, -boxC.z);
    glTranslated(boxC.x-xTrans, 0, 0);
    glTranslated(0, boxC.y+yTrans, 0);
    glTranslated(0, 0, boxC.z+zTrans);
    glRotated( xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRotated( yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glRotated( zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    glTranslated(-boxC.x+xTrans, 0, 0);
    glTranslated(0, -boxC.y-yTrans, 0);
    glTranslated(0, 0, -boxC.z-zTrans);
    glTranslated( -xTrans, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glTranslated( 0.0, yTrans, 0.0 );
    glTranslated( 0.0, 0.0, zTrans );

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < m_points.size(); i++)
    {
        Vector3D P = m_points[i];
        glVertex3d(P.x, P.y, P.z);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```